# Displaying DateTime in Xamarin.Forms with SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite-net, xamarin.forms.listview

I am creating a Xamarin.Forms application for a school project. This project displays a list of school terms (6-month blocks of time) with the start and end dates. The list of the terms displays without issues, but the dates do not appear as expected: all dates are 01/01/0001. The terms table is:

```
    Id          TermName    StartDate   EndDate   
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           Term 1      2020-01-01  2020-06-30
2           Term 2      2020-07-01  2020-12-31
3           Term 3      2021-01-01  2021-06-30
4           Term 4      2021-07-01  2021-12-31
5           Term 5      2022-01-01  2022-06-30
6           Term 6      2022-07-01  2022-12-31
```

Since SQLite doesn't have a specific DATETIME data type, I'm storing the StartDate and EndDate as a TEXT data type, but the terms.cs model file uses the DateTime datatype. Placing a breakpoint at the loading of the list of terms shows:
[Breakpoint data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZByGk.png).

Terms.cs file:

```
[Table("Terms")]
    public class Terms
    {
        public int Term { get; set; }
        public string TermName { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

MainPage.xaml.cs file:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DBLocation))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<Terms>();
                var terms = conn.Table<Terms>().ToList();
                TermsListView.ItemsSource = terms;
                TermsListView.SelectedItem = null;
            }
        }
```

How do I get the StartDate and EndDate from my table to show up in my ListView correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you store it as a `string` the value cannot be assigned to the `DateTime` properties (no automatic conversion). So they keep their default date.
Change the properties to:

```
 public class Terms
    {
        public int Term { get; set; }
        public string TermName { get; set; }
        public string StartDate { get; set; }
        public string EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Then display these properties or convert the value to a real `DateTime` type:

```
public class Terms
        {
            public int Term { get; set; }
            public string TermName { get; set; }
            public string StartDate { get; set; }
            public string EndDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime RealStartDate => DateTime.Parse(StartDate);
            public DateTime RealEndDate => DateTime.Parse(EndDate);
        }
```

The `Parse` method is not tested by me but you can look up the correct syntax if the result is not what you need.

In you View you should then use the  `RealStartDate` and `RealEndDate` properties

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in ListView

```
     <Label
                                        FontSize="18"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        Text="{Binding StartDate, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}" />
<Label
                                        FontSize="18"
                                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                        Text="{Binding EndDate, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}" />
```